# Assigning a string containing colon (:) and minus sign (-) in bash to a local variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to assign an AWS ARN value to a `local` bash variable as shown in the function below

```
function attach () {
  let lb="arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:1234334545:loadbalancer/app/myservice/ab3434dc0f";
   # other processingin
 }
```

Which is leading to error saying

```
let: lb=arn\:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:1234334545:loadbalancer/app/myservice/ab3434dc0f: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:1234334545:loadbalancer/app/myservice/ab3434dc0f")
```

After searching a bit, I found out that the colon (:) operators does a lot of things in bash. And looking at error here, I guess it is trying to assign rest of the string to `arn`. However, I could not find a way to escape this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use let, thats for arithmetic operations. `lb="yadda:yadda"` is sufficient.

Comment: @123 thanks, I believe I should have used `local` instead of `let`.